# Не могу достучаться на веб-сервер в контейнере Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, веб-сервер

При запуске команды

```
docker compose up
```

У меня запускается контейнер, на котором есть веб-сервис на Flask. Вот что мне показывает в командной строке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я могу посылать на него запросы по адресу http://localhost:8000 и все работает. Я закрываю этот контейнер, нажав Ctrl+c, и пытаюсь его запустить через команду docker run :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы запустилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но запросы не посылаются, пишет:

```
Error: Couldn't connect to server
```

Я пробовал менять порт на 5000, и название сервера менять на  http://127.0.0.1 и http://172.17.0.4, но так же не могу достучаться до сервера. **Как мне найти адрес, по которому я могу достучаться до сервера?**

И добавка к этому вопросу:

Нажимаю Ctrl+c, чтобы остановить веб-сервер, но сервер не останавливается. Могу выключить сервер только закрыв командную строку. **Почему так?**

Comment: Закрыл запущенные контейнеры, но проблема не решилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При запуске через `docker run` по умолчанию порты контейнера не доступны снаружи. При запуске контейнера нужно опубликовать нужный порт (ключ командной строки `-p`), и после двоеточия указать под каким номером порта он будет доступен снаружи (если не указать, то порт контейнера будет доступен снаружи через порт со случайным номером).

Соответственно, вам нужно запускать так:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 ...
```

Документация: [Container networking / Published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

Comment: В моем случае это 8000:5000, но спасибо, помогло

Comment: Ну это уже детали. У вас нигде в вопросе не указано, что вы flask запускаете на порту 8000.